# iOS JavaScript bridge binding

Tags: ios, bridge

The JavaScript bridge was check the operation as follows in ios.

However, it does not work in a part of the JavaScript.

It would be no way to dont work only part of the prototype format?

ios code.

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    JSContext *ctx = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

    ctx[@"window"][@"mobilebridge"] = @{};

    ctx[@"window"][@"mobilebridge"][@"printMessage"] = ^(JSValue *message){
          NSLog(@"printMessage----------------------------------================");
                  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:message.toString preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

          UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Alrty Message" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){}];
          [alert addAction:ok];
          [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

          __block int value = 10;
          return ^{
            return ++value;
          };
    };

    ctx[@"window"][@"mobilebridge"][@"testPrintMessage"] = ^(JSValue *pMessageId){
        NSLog(@"testPrintMessage----------------------------------================");

        return ^{
            return @"1234";
        };
    };
}
```

JavaScript code.

```
function loadTest(){

    var test = "test";
    //run
    var aaa = window.mobilebridge.printMessage("test");
    //not run
    var tttt = CommonTest.testPrint(test); 
}

CommonTest.prototype.testPrint = function (pDispatch)
{
    var resValue;
    resValue = (function(){window.mobilebridge.testPrintMessage(pDispatch); }());

    return resValue;
}
```